# Increasing an images size over time?

Tags: xcode, swift

I have an image that needs to increase in size over time. How would I go about doing that?

> var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: Selector("grow"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

For the actual function I am confused how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a fluid animation, use this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, animations: { () -> Void in
    imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0, 2.0)
})
```